# NodeIterator or TreeWalker objects in JSDOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-traversal, jsdom

I'm trying to use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) in node.js to do a small transformation to an HTML document. When doing my client-side tests, I used the `document.createTreeWalker` and `document.createNodeIterator` functions, which are [part of the DOM 2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/traversal.html)...however, they're not apparently part of jsdom, even though its authors claim that it has full DOM1 and DOM2 compatibility. Am I missing something? Are these functions available in a document created by jsdom?

```
$ node
> var jsdom = require('jsdom');
> var doc = jsdom.jsdom('<div>Test</div><div>One</div><div>Two</div>');
> doc.createTreeWalker(doc)
TypeError: Object [ null ] has no method 'createTreeWalker'
    at [object Context]:1:5
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:171:22)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:153:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:408:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:585:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:73:12)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:81:20)
    at ReadStream._emitKey (tty_posix.js:307:10)
    at ReadStream.onData (tty_posix.js:70:12)
```

Comment: That's not DOM2, that's DOM2 traversal range. There's a difference. jsdom does not support it

Comment: Ah, thank you. I guess I'm not clear on where the spec begins and ends.